# $ J = \displaystyle\int_0^1 \left(\left(y'\right)^2-a^2y^2\right)dx $ and $ J_1= \displaystyle\int_0^1 \left(y' + ay \tan bx\right)^2dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let
>   $$ J = \int_0^1 \left(\left(y'\right)^2-a^2y^2\right)dx $$
>   where a is a given positive constant and y is a given function of $x$, not identically zero, satisfying $y=0$ at $x=1$. By considering an integral of the form $$ J_1= \int_0^1 \left(y' + ay \tan bx\right)^2dx$$
>   where b is suitably chosen, show that $ J \geq 0$. You should state the range of values of $a$ in the form $a<k$, for which your proof is valid. In the case  $a=k$, find a function $y$ (not everywhere zero) such that $J=0$.

I only have problem with the very last part.
For the previous parts:

Choose $b = a$

$$J_1 = J + \left[ay^2\tan{ax}\right]_0^1$$
$$=> J = J_1$$
range of value of $a<\dfrac \pi 2$ since the function must be continuous.

$$\left(y' + ay\tan {ax}\right)^2 \geq 0 => J\geq 0$$
Now

$a=k$, and Since $J=0$ 
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx} + ky\tan{kx} = 0$$ 
$$=> y\cos {kx} = 0$$

But $y$ is not "everywhere $0$" as stated in the question??

Solution paper says:

> $y = \cos{ax}$

Why is it so?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $\tan(x)\cos(x)=\sin(x), \partial_x \cos(x)=-\sin(x)$

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but since you cannot use a non-trivial solution (i.e. $y=0$), so you need to solve the differential equation. You can use separation of variable for this. Thereupon, it should be obvious why the solution is as such. Also, good luck for your STEP test.

Comment: @nexolute This has appeared in STEP, but also in the Part IB Cambridge Tripos under the Variational Principles course - And, I presume, elsewhere too.

Comment: @FH93 Ah, I didn't know that. I assumed its STEP since I'm taking it soon too.

Comment: It indeed is a question from 2014 STEP 3 paper, thank you nexolute and good luck to you too. (But given  you are already studying 'Concrete mathematics' I don't think you need one :) ). May I ask how you finding that book? I've heard that book starts nice then gets really hard later on such that you are expected to spend a day or even a week on a single question. That book has got some really good reviews but given that I find STEP 3 hard already it may be too much of a leap for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you cannot consider $J_1$ in the case $a=\pi /2$, given that the integral no longer converges so solving $y'+(\pi/2)y\tan (\pi x/2)=0$ is pointless as it not longer has a sensible implication for $J$.

Instead, you want to consider $J$ itself; in particular, integrating the first term by parts with $u=y'$:

$$J=0 \iff \underbrace{y(1)y'(1)}_{=0 \ by \ IC}-y(0)y'(0) - \displaystyle\int_0^1 y(y''+(\pi/2)^2y)dx = 0$$

So seeking $y$ such that

$$y'' + (\pi/2)^2 y =0, \ y(0)=0 \ (\text{or} \ y'(0)=0)$$

is sufficient, and the latter initial condition clearly yields the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, May I ask your last line.
$y'' - (\dfrac \pi 2)^2y = 0 => m = 0$ or $\pi /2$. Giving $y=A+Be^{\frac {\pi} {2} x}$. It seems that you derived $y=\cos {ax}$ from that latter condition and the initial $y(1) =0$. But what about this differential equation? looks like I can try to find the value of A or B.

Comment: Initial condition gives $A=-Be^{\frac \pi 2}$ but I am not sure which value to take.. $y(0)=0$ or $y'(0)=0$..

Comment: Ah, that's my mistake. It should have been $y'' + (\pi/2)^2y = 0$. But further to that, assuming that $m$ is the root of your auxiliary equation, $m=0$ is never a solution. Rather $m=\pm i\pi /2$. The second initial condition gives a cosine. The former gives a sine.